# How long does acetone stay in ABS?

Tags: solvents

I know a larger part of this question is "it depends", since scales matter here. Let's bound ourselves to desktop 3D-printed objects, which will typically be no more than a few cm thick.

After an hour or so of acetone vapor smoothing, some people have noticed that ABS parts can bubble a week or two later. Below is an example of where an ABS part deformed when exposed to constant heat.

[image]

It makes sense to me that once the acetone is subsurface that it will just as easily continue to work its way deeper into the part as head toward the surface and evaporate.

On a long enough time line, though, all the acetone will eventually work its way to the surface and liberate itself from the plastic.

How can I determine that timeline? I would have thought it was hours, but empirical evidence seems to suggest it's at least weeks, if not longer.

(I'm making an assumption here and that's that acetone is a harmless solvent and will not permanently modify the plastic. It's unclear if that assumption is completely correct.)

Comment: If you're going to downvote, esp. if you're downvoting a new contributor, please take the time to explain why you think this question is not appropriate for SE.Chemistry.

Comment: Since acetone turns a solid object into goop, why do you consider it “harmless”? Do printed objects not exposed to acetone behave the same way?

Comment: Since, as you state, the effect varies, you'd need to experiment with **you're** printer and feed stock, to eliminate some of the **many** variables such as feed composition, printing temperature, heating time, thickness, temperature of piece and acetone vapor in smoothing, temperature and airflow for *removing* absorbed vapors, etc.

Comment: @JonCusterr "harmless" in reference to the material chemistry. I.e., water will dissolve table salt, but when the water evaporates the original salt remains chemically unchanged. I don't know if this is true about acetone and ABS.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Those aren't my parts, but I would still like to know more about the first principles involved. I am hoping for a more rigorous approach than trial and error. Happy to rephrase the question if that would be appropriate.

Comment: @KennSebesta, rigorously, the solvent *never* completely leaves the workpiece; it's depletion curve is logarithmic, and, though concentration decreases over time, consider that it halves, and halves again, and halves yet again. It also would not be uniform with depth. If you could measure the rate, and establish what would be an allowable remainder of solvent, you could find this yourself.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I agree with that, but I feel like it describes every physical process. They all asymptotically converge toward some stability point, whether it's chemistry, electricity, mechanics, etc... The difference is, as you rightly point out, the rates and the acceptable levels. I ask the question in hopes they are already well understood, and those answers can be provided here.